# Cómo realizar el parpadeo, sin gasto excesivo de memoria?

Tags: javascript, rendimiento

Quiero hacer una estrella que parpadee, se me ocurre hacer

Un `div` en forma de circulo y en *Javascript* con un `setInterval` hacerla desaparecer y aparecer rapidamente, de esta forma:

Y aunque el algoritmo total en sí, no es lo importante, el enfoque de mi código es usar setInterval, por lo cual mi duda es:

> ¿Cuanto afectará hacer un setInterval ?

**En realidad es un setTimeout, pero funciona como setInterval y que es infinito.**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", _init);

function _init (){
 var stars = document.getElementsByClassName("star");
 Array.from(stars).forEach(star => {
 parpadeo(star, 1, 2);
 });
}

function parpadeo (star,flag, state){
 if(flag > 0 && state%2 === 0) {
   flag -= 0.25;
   setTimeout(()=> {
   star.style.opacity = flag;
   if(flag <= 0) state++;
   parpadeo(star, flag, state);
   }, 50);
 }
 else if(state%2 !== 0) {
   flag += 0.25;
   setTimeout(()=> {
   star.style.opacity = flag;
   if(flag >= 1) state++;
   parpadeo(star, flag, state);
   }, 50);
 }
}
```

```css
body {background-color: black;}
.star {
 width: 4px; height: 4px; background-color: white; border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar **css** y hacer una animación

```
@keyframes example {
  0% {background:  rgb(255, 255, 255);}//inicio
  100% {background:  rgba(255, 255, 255,0);}//final
}
```

y para agregarla

```
animation:example infinite .4s
```

> la animaciones en **css** te van a quitar mucho menos memoria que una funcion en **js**

**Ejemplo funcional**

```css
body {background-color: black;}
.star {
 width: 4px; height: 4px; background-color: white; border-radius: 50%;
 animation:example infinite .4s
}
@keyframes example {
    0% {background:  rgb(255, 255, 255);}
    100% {background:  rgba(255, 255, 255,0);}
}
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
```

### ¿Qué son las animaciones CSS?

- Una animación permite que un elemento cambie gradualmente de un estilo a otro.
- Puede cambiar tantas propiedades CSS que desee, tantas veces como desee.
- Para usar animación CSS, primero debe especificar algunos fotogramas clave para la animación.
- Los fotogramas clave mantienen qué estilos tendrá el elemento en determinados momentos.

---

### Rendimiento de CSS en comparación con JavaScript

Existe una gran cantidad de páginas y comentarios en la web en los cuales se tratan las ventajas relativas de las animaciones de CSS y JavaScript desde la perspectiva del rendimiento. A continuación se muestran algunos puntos que debes tener en cuenta:

Las animaciones basadas en CSS, y las animaciones web cuando exista compatibilidad nativa, generalmente se manejan con un subproceso conocido como “subproceso compositor”. Es diferente al “subproceso principal” del navegador, donde se ejecutan el estilo, el diseño, la pintura y JavaScript. Esto significa que, si el navegador tiene en ejecución algunas tareas con alta demanda de recursos en el subproceso principal, es muy probable que las animaciones se sigan ejecutando sin interrupciones.

En muchos casos, el subproceso compositor también puede administrar otras modificaciones de las propiedades transforms y opacity.

Si alguna animación activa elementos de pintura, diseño o de ambas clases, el “subproceso principal” deberá hacer el trabajo. Esto se aplica a las animaciones basadas en CSS y JavaScript, y es probable que la sobrecarga de diseño o pintura reduzca la cantidad de trabajo asociado con la ejecución de CSS o JavaScript, por lo cual el asunto sería irrelevante.

Fuente: [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animations-and-performance?hl=es#css-vs-javascript-performance)

Comment: el 0% y el 100%, a que corresponden?